# Getting RDP Access what ports to use/open up?

Tags: remote-desktop

I am currently attempting to get remote desktop server access to a different server, and that server admin was asking me what ports I was using. I was unsure to what he meant, and how I could find out this info  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's Windows remote desktop, then TCP port 3389 is what you need to tell him, although I'd like to think the admin should know that information!

Comment: Hey Roger, thanks for that. So basically I guess all I need to give him is my IP Address and tell him my port is 3389 ?

Comment: That should be enough, yes, although really the sysadmin should be able to tell you all this ... I'm a little concerned that he can't! There could be other network security in place, but IP and port is a good place to start from!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default configuration it will be port 3389 that the server is listening on. For non-standard configurations it can be anything, only the server administrator will be able to tell you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol